# How to connect node app to server via socket.io?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have a simple app running on docker container. This container is not running all the time. It starts, does certain job and stops. When it is up, I would like to connect it to a server via socket.io. I have tried to use `socket.io-client` but still unable to make it works. This is my app code:

```
var docker_host_ip = process.env.DOCKER_HOST_IP;


var address = 'http://' + docker_host_ip +":" + port;
console.log("console : " + address);

var socket = require('socket.io-client')(address);
socket.on("disconnect", function(){
  console.log("disconnected ");
});


socket.on("connect_failed", function(err){
  console.log("err : " + err);
});

socket.on('connect', function(){
  console.log("connected");
});

socket.on('news', function(data){
  console.log("data : " + data);
  socket.emit("news", {docker: "This is docker"});
});
socket.emit("news", {docker: "This is docker"});

socket.on('error', function (err) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

I used this https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client.

```
var port = 4000;
app.use(express.static('.'))

var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

io.on('connection', function(socket){                                                                                                                        
  socket.emit("news", {"hello": "hello"});
  socket.on("news", function(data){
    console.log( "new " + data);
    io.sockets.emit("news", data);
  });

  socket.on('disconnect', function() {
    console.log('Got disconnect!');
  });

});




app.get("/", function(res, req){
  req.sendFile(path.join('/index.html'));
});


http.listen(port, function(){                                                                                                                                
  console.log('listening on *' + port);
});
```

My app is not showing any error, but not message is sent. My server is working correctly through browser (with socket.io).
Can someone please tell me what is wrong ?

Comment: what is the difference between the first part and second part??

Comment: The client emits a [`connect_error`](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client#events) event in case of connection errors, which you're not listening for.

Comment: I am trying to cash error. But still not error, no reaction.

Comment: @DonaldWu the server uses seocket.io and the client socket.io-client

Comment: @dmx does the `connect` event fire at all?

Comment: @robertklep it seems it is doing anything. there is no reaction.

Comment: @dmx in that case, telnet to `$DOCKER_HOST_IP` + port and see if you can even connect to it.

Comment: @robertklep I have tried with `curl ` and it is working find

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two same socket.emit message names, I guess the server send the message first.

**server**

```
socket.emit("news", {"hello": "hello"});

socket.on("news1", function(data){
    console.log( "new " + data);
    io.sockets.emit("news2", data);
});
```

**client**

```
socket.on('news', function(data){
  console.log("data : " + data);
  socket.emit("news1", {docker: "This is docker"});
});


socket.on('news2', function(data){
  console.log("data : " + data);
});
```